# Cannot install bootstrap in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, ng-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

Initially I installed bootstrap using below command:

npm install --save bootstrap

It was installed successfully and I am trying to add CSS like below:

```
"styles": [     
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
   "styles.css"
],
```

In angular cli file. But when i run the project i got the error like below.

```
@ ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-
 loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./src/styles.css 3:10-192 
@ ./src/styles.css 
@ multi ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./src/styles.css
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because, there is an issue with bootstrap 4.0.0.
Downgrade bootstrap version to `4.0.0-beta.2` in `package.json`.

```
"bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2"
```

[For more information check this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9020)

or you can upgrade angular-cli version as it is suggested in the thread. Mine is 1.6.3